# MainActivity.onCreate java.lang.IllegalStateException - Screen fragments should never be restored

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have been developing an app for android and ios using React Native 0.69.0, and just recently I discovered that putting the app in split-screen or freeform mode (from being the only app on the screen) sometimes causes it to crash.

Also, I used **Firebase to track issues** like this, and here are some logs:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Screen fragments should never be restored. Follow                instructions from https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/17#issuecomment-424704067 to properly configure your main activity.
       at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.<init>(ScreenFragment.kt:54)
       at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment.<init>(ScreenStackFragment.kt:35)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:613)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2728)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:198)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$2.onContextAvailable(FragmentActivity.java:149)
       at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable(ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:322)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:273)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:45)
       at com.cwlabou.cryptowallet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8103)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1359)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3713)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3898)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execut`your text`e(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2305)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8192)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Runti
meInit.java:626)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
```

If I will do something like this

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    // super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
}
```

It will fix the issue of not showing up in Firebase, but unfortunately, these changes will prevent savedInstance from being saved. So, every time the user opens the app, they will see the first screen.